# Update a column when closing a window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a table of records that has a column `processed`. In my web page i'm using sessions.. because every user that opens the page should see different data from the table.. so i initially have `processed=0` and when i'm selecting my data i'm updating the column where `processed=0` and then i'm updating the column to `processed=2`  so that way if another opens the page he gets other data... but the problem is that if the user closes the page without changing anything about the page i need to put my column back to 0 `processed=0` but i can't handle an event on the close button of the page... and also not on the log out because they may close the page without logging out... so does anyone has any idea how can i manage this?

note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

Answer (score 0):

for what you need, don't rely on some browser action, i.e. browser close button (what if internet goes down for one of the users :) ).

The simple way to achieve this is to perform somekind of polling at both levels, i.e. in the db(since your flag is stored in the db) and at the code. Polling implies, constantly making request for certain operation after a fixed interval of time. Obviously, polling is taxing, but it is one of the solution.

Another way to do is to as soon as your user Logs in, you create a Http Long lived request, which neither of the parties(client and server) break and as soon as it ends, you set the flag to 0 again, but having a parallel long lasting request along with all those others is not simple. It is termed as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

So I would recommend, to constantly make an ajax request say every 2minutes, to update a certain field, say `LastActive` in user accounts table. This would constitute your Code side Polling

and Then create a sql server job, which constantly monitors this `LastActive` field and say, if the difference between it and current DateTime is more than 2.10 minutes, it sets the processed=0 for that user.

You can also look into SessionExpire fields(or whatever it is called), if you are using Forms Authentication of ASP.NET through Session